# How do you remove everything within parenthesis in BQSQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

What I'm trying to accomplish is I have a column that is a String that has parenthesis that I want to have removed completely when I query the results for example:

```
12345 | Test | Test 1 (12345)
34567 | Test | Test 2 (34567)
67899 | Test | Test 3 (67899)
```

What I want the results to be is:

```
12345 | Test | Test 1
34567 | Test | Test 2
67899 | Test | Test 3
```

I know there is a way to do this, I'm just not finding the correct query to remove everything from parenthesis to parenthesis. I'm able to remove the `()` itself, but not the numbers within the `()` and I think there is an easier way of doing this instead of making a complicated query because of it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple method is:

```
select replace(col3, concat(' (', col1, ')'), '')
```

This specifically removes the parentheses when they contain the first column.

If you want everything before the first paren:

```
select split(col3, ' (')[safe_ordinal(1)]
```

Or:

```
select left(col3, instr(col3, ' ('))
```

Comment: This is perfect! I completely forgot about the `Split` function and works perfect for what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider below example

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 12345 col1, 'Test' col2, 'Test 1 (12345)' col3 union all
  select 34567, 'Test', 'Test 2 (34567)' union all
  select 67899, 'Test', 'Test 3 (67899)' 
)
select col1, col2, 
  trim(regexp_replace(col3, r'\(.+\)', '')) col3
from `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

[image]